# iPad 2 still image capturing only 720x960 with AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto

Tags: ios, video, camera, capture

I'm capturing video and showing a live preview using [`AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html). In between I want to be able to capture full quality still images. Therefore I for the most part followed [this tutorial](http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=1297).

If I set the session preset to [`AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVCaptureSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html), I only get a 720x960 output image instead of the full rear camera resolution 1280x720. However if I explicitly set `AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720`, I get the full resolution. On iPhone 5, I always get the full resolution with `AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto` (3264x2448). Do I really have to do `if iPad2 do this, else do that` or am I missing some option here?

The AVCaptureStillImageOutput format is set to default (JPEG-compressed), but the same happens if I use uncompressed BGRA (`setOutputSettings` with dictionary containing `kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey => kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA`).

Answer (score 0):

You are obtaining the image at the correct resolution.
iPad2 have a 960x720 camera and if you use the `AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto` preset you'll get that resolution.

Forcing the `AVCaptureSessionPreset1280x720` preset you are telling iOS to use a video recording preset, that actually can reach an higher resolution (it is an HD 720p camera - 1280x720).